# Segmentation fault: but why?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int* ptr;
 *ptr = 5;
 printf("%d", &ptr);
 return 0;
}
```

This was asked in a coding interview, what should be the output?

I am confused between runtime error, compilation error and segmentation fault.

Anyone who can explain why will the answer be segmentation fault?

Comment: The correct answer is "undefined behaviour"

Comment: But the answer key mentions it to be segmentation fault, Anyway, can you explain me what the code line-by-line i.e. what type of error will result? @M.M

Comment: Do you have room for `ptr`? in other words, is `ptr` pointing to some valid (initialized) or dinamically allocated address?

Comment: By the way, I ran it on onlineGDB and it shows segmentation fault

Comment: no @DavidRanieri

Comment: Thus... *undefined behavior*. You're dereferencing an indeterminate pointer. And fyi, `%d` is not the proper format specifier for an address., which `&ptr` (which I also suspect is both undesired and quite-incorrect) clearly is. Regardless, @M.M is quite right. There is absolutely no guarantee this code will seg-fault. The only guarantee is, starting with the second line of `main`, there are no guarantees whatsoever. So goes the very nature of *undefined* behavior. If the "answer" key says otherwise, the author is either naïve or kidding themselves (probably both).

Comment: The "answer key" is wrong

Comment: @GirG then that's the reason, you are trying to write to some random address, probably an address without read/write permissions and the system protects itself by launching a segfault

Comment: [Illegal instruction](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fa49hn), [compilation error](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bjscrG)

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behavior because the pointer was left uninitialized. You need to initialize the pointer first before inserting into it anything:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * REQ_SIZE);
```

After this, you will no longer get a segfault. Note that you need to put a dereference operator instead of `&` to print the containing value of the integer pointer.

Here's a [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/xXCQkpanb).

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the definition of Pointers. **Pointer** is a variable whose value is the address of another variable, i.e. direct address of the memory location. Here in your case, ptr is declared as an integer pointer, which isn't pointing to any address. That's why it gives Segmentation Fault Error. **Segmentation fault** is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you". Instead of this you can do 2 things :

1. Assign a new integer variable's address to the pointer :

```
    int x;
    int *ptr = &x;
    *ptr = 5;
```

2. Initializing the pointer using the `malloc()` :

```
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE_REQUIRED);
```

Also note that by using the reference of `ptr` in the `printf()` prints the address of the pointer rather than the value contained by the address it is referring to. It is demonstrated here :

```
    printf("%d", ptr);  // Prints the address of the pointer variable.
    printf("%d", *ptr);  // Prints the value (in this case : 5) contained by the address referenced by the pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Compilation error** is an error that you face while your program is being compiled by the compiler and it's due to C grammar (Maybe you wrote an incorrect instruction grammatically.)

**Runtime error** is an error that you face when your program is running.

**Segmentation fault** is an error that you face when you're trying to access to a location in the memory that you're not allowed to access to it such as a location indicated by null pointers.

Your program has undefined behavior. Because pointers store a memory address and they cannot store a value such as a number. You could allocate some memory from heap and then you can store a value in your pointer:

```
int *ptr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
*ptr = 5;
```

Or you could declare a local variable and store its address in `ptr`:

```
int value = 5;
int *ptr = &value;
```